# Show $a_n \rightarrow L$ and if $a_n \leq L, \exists a_{n_k} \rightarrow L$

Tags: real-analysis

Show If $a_n \rightarrow L$ and if $a_n \leq L$ for infinitely many values of n$ , \exists a_{n_k} \rightarrow L$ and increasing.

So far I considered $a_n = 2 - 1/n$

Comment: you're supposed to find this for *any* sequence which satisfies your conditions, not just construct one. For monotone, converging sequence the statement is obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is false as written.  If $a_n=L$ for all $n$, then there is no strictly increasing subsequence.  If you insist that $a_n<L$ for infinitely many values or allow for nondecreasing sequences, then the statement is correct.

Hint: Let $a_n<L$.  You can find an $a_m$ so that $m>n$, $a_n<a_m<L$, and $|a_m-L|<\frac{1}{2}|a_n-L|$.  (If no such $m$ existed, then the sequence would not converge to $L$).   The values of $m$ constructed in this way will be your $a_{n_i}$'s.

Answer (score 1):

First, if $\exists n_0 \forall n\ge n_0:a_n=L$, then the question is obvious. So we assume that there are infinitely many indices such that $a_n<L$.

Next, we can assume that $a_n<L$ **for all** $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (otherwise, replace $a_n$ by any subsequence $a_{n_j}$ such that $\forall n_j:a_{n_j}\leq L$.

Now, we assume that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:a_n<L$. We build $a_{n_k}$ by induction: Take $a_{n_1}=a_1$, and for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\ge 2$, if $a_{n_{k-1}}$ is given, take $a_{n_k}$ such that
$$\frac{a_{n_{k-1}}+L}{2}<a_{n_k}<L$$
(note that we if we require $a_{n_{k-1}}<a_{n_k}$, we will get an increasing subsequence, but it won't necessarily converge to $L$.)

The intuition: each time the distance between $a_{n_k}$ and $L$ decreases at least by $2$ (meaning, it will be at most half of the distance before).

Now, prove that $a_{n_k}$ we built is increasing and converges to $L$.